# Nothing happens when processing mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, connection

I am trying to create a login system with MySQL and PHP:

```
<?php
    ... irrelevant login code removed ...

    session_start();
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","test_database");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM users");
    echo $result;
?>
```

But the page in question displays nothing. Why is this happening?

Thank you!

Comment: `$result` is a resource. You cannot echo it out. You can use it to do other mysql operations like `mysql_fetch_array` etc. By the way `mysql_` is deprecated. Try using PDO.

Comment: You can't mix `mysqli_*` functions with `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: in addition to the above comment by Mike , u should also fetch your result in order see your data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't mix `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*` functions.
2. You need to retrieve the data from your result set before you can use it.

Try this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","test_database");
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT firstname FROM users") or die(mysqli_error($con));

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
      echo $key.': '.$value."\n";
    }
    echo "-------------\n";
  }
  ?>
```